# Atom Prettier adds dependencies in useEffect at auto save

Tags: atom-editor, prettier, prettier-eslint

I have [prettier](https://atom.io/users/prettier) installed in my [Atom](https://atom.io/) editor. I enabled autosave option. but on auto save when it changes useEffect dependency array most of time. I don't want atom to auto add element in dependency array. I would really appreciate if someone can guide me to the prettier config which enables / disables this feature -

following are example of changes.

**Original:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchListPlants());
}, []);
```

**After Autosave:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchListPlants());
}, [dispatch]);
```

**Original:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    geocoder.addTo('#geocoder');
    dispatch(fetchListQuotes());
}, []);
```

**After Autosave:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    geocoder.addTo('#geocoder');
    dispatch(fetchListQuotes());
}, [geocoder, dispatch]);
```

My **Prettier.json**

```
{
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "endOfLine": "auto",
    "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
    "insertPragma": false,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 120,
    "proseWrap": "preserve",
    "quoteProps": "as-needed",
    "requirePragma": false,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "useTabs": false,
    "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false
  }
```

Comment: Why do you suspect a code-formatter to alter your code functionality. That's not what `prettier` does.

Comment: @idleberg because when I disable this one package and save. dependencies doesn't get added automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [dependencies](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-atom/blob/ae9972e561687e4af00a3fd1786c3a8fd0a97ce7/package.json#L25) of `prettier-atom`, I'm suspecting that the ESLint integration might be causing this. ESLint reports missing dependencies for `useEffect()`, but I'm not sure if that rule falls in the category of fixable errors.

Either way, try disabling the ESLint Integration in the `prettier-atom` settings to see if the problem persists:

[image]

You can find the settings of that Atom package at `Settings > Packages > prettier-atom`

Comment: that makes sense. but how to disable the setting, I don't see any rule for that in prettier's docs https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html

Comment: I've update my answer with a screenshot of the package settings

Comment: yup. that was the issue